# Why does my Touchbar's Control Strip no longer control iTunes?

Tags: touch-bar

I re-arranged the icons on my control strip, and now the playback buttons (play/pause, next, previous) no longer control playback in the Music/iTunes app.

I've already tried:
* restarting my computer
* resetting the control strip to default options

The music buttons in the "App Actions" section when iTunes is in focus does work, but not the ones in the Control Strip which shows when other apps are selected.

Comment: Tried anything like this: https://gearpatrol.com/2017/10/02/how-to-reset-the-touch-bar-on-your-macbook-pro/ or this: https://9to5mac.com/2020/01/20/mac-how-to-fix-and-restart-the-touch-bar/

Comment: Tried both. Neither works.